# Is a compact surface where the principal curvatures coincide everywhere a sphere?

Tags: surfaces, curvature

Suppose $S$ is a compact surface where in every point $P$ the principal curvatures $C_{1}(P)$ and $C_{2}(P)$ fulfill $C_{1}(P)=C_{2}(P)$.

Is $S$ necessarily a sphere? My idea is that the compacity hypothesis implies that the image of the Gauss curvature is bounded, and that the equality of principal curvatures implies the isotropy of its distribution. Is that enough to conclude?

Edit: if the map $P\mapsto K(P)$ is analytic, Liouville theorem may allow us to deduce it is constant on $S$.

Comment: Are you asking whether $S$ is *diffeomorphic* or *isometric* to a sphere?

Comment: Actually I ask if the Gauss curvature $K(P)=C_{1}(P)C_{2}(P)$ is constant on $S$.

Comment: If the principal curvatures are equal, search for _totally umbilic surface_ and _Liebmann's theorem_. If instead the Gaussian curvature is constant (an _a priori_ weaker hypothesis), it's important to specify whether you're speaking of a surface in Euclidean three-space or not.